# How to add new data to an existing graph with plot.ly

Tags: node.js, plotly

I want to add new data to an existing graph. Meaning that I want to merge the existing rendered data points with new ones to render the old and the new data points together. I'm trying to use `Plotly.newPlot` to render new data like this:

```
const TESTER = document.getDocumentById('tester');
const dataPoints = {
    x: [1, 2, 3], 
    y: [1, 2, 3], 
    text: ['1 text', '2 text', '3 text '], 
    size: [1, 2, 3], 
    color: [1, 2, 3]
};
const layout = {
    margin: {
        t: 0
    },
    hovermode: 'closest'
};
const dataToRender = {
    x: [dataPoints.x],
    y: [dataPoints.y],
    text: [dataPoints.text],
    mode: 'markers',
    marker: {
        size: dataPoints.size,
        color: dataPoints.color,
        sizemode: 'area',
        showscale: true,
        colorscale: 'Portland',
        colorbar: {
            xanchor: 'right',
            len: 0.5,
            title: 'km'
        }
    }
};

Plotly.newPlot(TESTER, dataToRender, layout);
```

But I always end up receiving a `plotly-latest.min.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like this is now possible with `Plotly.extendTraces`? https://plot.ly/javascript/streaming/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plotly format is sometimes a bit tricky. You need to change the data structure as follows:

```
const dataToRender = [{
    x: dataPoints.x,
    y: dataPoints.y,
    text: dataPoints.text,
    mode: 'markers',
    marker: {
        size: dataPoints.size,
        color: dataPoints.color,
        sizemode: 'area',
        showscale: true,
        colorscale: 'Portland',
        colorbar: {
            xanchor: 'right',
            len: 0.5,
            title: 'km'
        }
    }
}];
```

i.e. all data goes in an array which contains the data itself and the metainformation, layout, etc.

- Add square brackets around your `dataToRender`
- Add curly brackets around `{x ...marker}`
- Remove the square brackets before `dataPoints.x`, `y` and `text`

Now let's get to the fun of adding data. We first make a variable out of your `const dataPoints` to store the initial data set (I modified the size a little bit). In the function `tester(`) we randomly add one point and update/redraw the graph.

```
<script>
    var dataPoints = {
        x: [1, 2, 3], 
        y: [1, 2, 3], 
        text: ['1 text', '2 text', '3 text '], 
        size: [50, 250, 500], 
        color: [1, 2, 3]
    }

    var t = setInterval(tester, 1000);

    function tester() {
        const TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');

        dataPoints.x.push(Math.random() * 3);
        dataPoints.y.push(Math.random() * 3);
        dataPoints.size.push(Math.random() * 500);
        dataPoints.color.push(1 + Math.random() * 2);

        const layout = {
            margin: {
                t: 0
            },
            hovermode: 'closest'
        };
        const dataToRender = [{
            x: dataPoints.x,
            y: dataPoints.y,
            text: dataPoints.text,
            mode: 'markers',
            marker: {
                color: dataPoints.color,
                size: dataPoints.size,
                sizemode: 'area',
                showscale: true,
                colorscale: 'Portland',
                colorbar: {
                    xanchor: 'right',
                    len: 0.5,
                    title: 'km'
                }
            }
            }];

        Plotly.newPlot(TESTER, dataToRender, layout);
    }
</script>
```

---

Here is the working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashafix/w1ft4fec/)

Comment: I tried what you told me and it did not merge the previous data points with the new ones, just shows the new ones. Also, It drew the new data points in lines, something like [this](https://www.google.es/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwisqvfZ_5jOAhWFVhoKHS4TDsQQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F37218319%2Fplotly-not-creating-linear-trend-line&psig=AFQjCNEoarc6ZJzI380-S9nH6WVHxkS1Yw&ust=1469892816896826), not data points, as I had them.

Comment: I skipped to point out that `size: dataPoints.size` and `color: dataPoints.color` are not shown aswell.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I updated my answer accordingly, hopefully that's what you need.

Comment: Your solution definitely works! Too bad that I was looking for an actual merge between new and old data inside Plotly. Your solution merge the data and then draws the graph every time there is a new data point to render. This approach is time consuming as it shows this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thorstorm/c3fr72yp/). I was hoping to find a way to just render each new data point to the graph without having to redraw the entire graph. I was pursuing something near streaming data points to Plotly. Thanks for your help, really appreciate.

Comment: Try this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thorstorm/c3fr72yp/1/) to see increasing time consuming as number of data points increase. "I make a lot of graphs" (Lisa Simpson) LOL

Comment: I really like your time plot, very informative! As far as I know the JS version of plotly doesn't really support streaming. I faced the same problem but didn't find a better solution than the one I posted.